# Does the Bible talk about denominations?

Tags: denomination-survey

**Is there any talk of differing religious denominations (of Christianity) in the Bible?**

Specific references to passages would be quite useful.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I think the situation in Corinth is comparable to there being different denominations.

> [**1 Corinthians 1:10-13 (ESV)**](http://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=1%20Corinthians%201:10-13&version=ESV)
>    <sup>10</sup> I appeal to you, brothers, by the name of our Lord Jesus Christ, that all of you agree, and that there be no divisions among you, but that you be united in the same mind and the same judgment. <sup>11</sup> For it has been reported to me by Chloe’s people that there is quarreling among you, my brothers. <sup>12</sup> What I mean is that each one of you says, "I follow Paul," or "I follow Apollos," or "I follow Cephas," or "I follow Christ." <sup>13</sup>  Is Christ divided? Was Paul crucified for you? Or were you baptized in the name of Paul?

This passage also quite clearly shows what Paul thinks of the situation. He talks more in-depth about this in chapters [**3**](http://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=1%20Corinthians%203&version=ESV) and [**12**](http://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=1%20Corinthians%2012&version=ESV).

Comment: +1.  Were we in Church together, you'd get an "Amen, Brother!" to that.  And maybe a high-five.

Comment: @DavidStratton but we *are* in (the universal) church together! Btw, I've been reading your blog and I really like it... God bless you, brother :)